# Is my representation of Mean Square Displacement good using this code?

Tags: csv, fiji

I use TrackMate in order to get the trajectories of particles, then it generates a csv file that contains positions in X, in Y and the corresponding times for each particle.
I tried calculating MSD using different approaches but the result seems odd to me every time. It should have a brownian motion so my results are not consistent. I expect to have an increasing curve overtime and that is not the case.

Here is the function I try to use:

```
def Mean3(filename, ax=None):
    # Step 1: Read CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, low_memory=False)

    # Step 2: Drop useless lines and columns

    df = df.drop(labels="LABEL", axis=1)
    df = df.drop(index=range(3), axis=0)
    df = df.astype(float)   #By default, str is the type

    # Step 3: Sort data
    df = df.sort_values(by=['TRACK_ID', 'POSITION_T'])

    # Step 4: Calculate the differences of position by time
    df['DX'] = df.groupby('TRACK_ID')['POSITION_X'].diff()
    df['DY'] = df.groupby('TRACK_ID')['POSITION_Y'].diff()

    # Step 5: Calculate MSD for each particle
    df['MSD'] = df['DX'] ** 2 + df['DY'] ** 2

    # Step 6: Calculate MSD mean for each time using all trajectories
    msd_mean = df.groupby('POSITION_T')['MSD'].mean()

    msd_mean_all = df.groupby('POSITION_T')['MSD'].mean()

    # Step 7: Check if the curve is increasing according to brownian motion
    if not np.all(np.diff(msd_mean.values) >= 0):
        print('La courbe MSD n\'est pas croissante conformément à un mouvement brownien !')

    # Step 8: Plot MSD global
    plt.plot(msd_mean_all.index, msd_mean_all.values, label="All trajectories")

    # Step 9: Calculate MSD for each trajectory
    msd_mean_traj = df.groupby(['TRACK_ID', 'POSITION_T'])['MSD'].mean().reset_index()

    # Step 10: Plot MSD for each trajectory
    for traj_id in msd_mean_traj['TRACK_ID'].unique():
        traj_data = msd_mean_traj[msd_mean_traj['TRACK_ID'] == traj_id]
        plt.plot(traj_data['POSITION_T'], traj_data['MSD'])

    plt.xlabel('Time T')
    plt.ylabel('Mean Square Displacement (MSD)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[My MSD representation I get using this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uv4b.png)